# Appcelerator Install Connector "ERROR: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, appcelerator

Appcelerator Install Connector

My computer spec iMac
  iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009)
  macOs Sierra 10.12.5

Node Version
  version 4.8.3

[Node Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRSUm.png)

I use command : **'appc install connector/appc.mysql'**

and I get error back in this message **'ERROR: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT'**

Below in image

[Error message after install: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jypP9.png)

Thank you